# Uncaught Reference Error ,require is not define , export is not deine

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a 5 years Javascript old project that I want to migrate to Typescript. Everything works fine but whenever I import or export something in or from the namespace, I get a runtime error. I tried a lot of solutions but nothing worked.

export not define: error for the following code

```
 export namespace Cloud-Service {
                  export function someservice(){
    //code goes here//
    }
        }
```

import {Cloud-Service } from "./util/cloud.ts" ----> require not define

[image]

Comment: Do you have some build system? What is your environment?

Comment: Its a customize build system from my company.

Comment: Does this happen during build time, or runtime?

Comment: Yeah it happened during the runtime and it's my second working on it but haven't find any solution.  My project dont accept any kind of import.

Comment: During runtime? i think this means your build system doesn't work correctly, because they final compiled JS should not have any "require" statements. We are talking about a frontend app, right?

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you. I communicate with the seniors and they said the problem is coming from build tool. But working to sort it out

Comment: Can you maybe upload your entire code to some repo?

Comment: Thank you i.brod but it's confidential. I am not supposed to upload it.